# Unable to connect with WIFI using wifiManger

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless

I am trying to connect with specific wifi but it is not working. Whenever i call a below code, already connected wifi stop and phone showing a wifi in scanning mode. Can someone tell me why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
 String result = "";
    try {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        int state = wifiManager.getWifiState();
        Log.i(TAG, "state: " + state);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String newSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        result = "Connected";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = "Failed";
        Log.e(TAG, "unable to set wifi " + ssid, e);
    }
```

Comment: Is this a open network?? If not then you need setup other configs also.

Comment: this is not open but already saved network in mobile. so i don't think so i need to give key along with configuration to connect with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not add SSID again. This code `wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig)` is adding another wifi profile to your device.

You just need below code to reconnect

```
private boolean connectToWifi(String ssid) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    List<WifiConfiguration> wifiList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration config : wifiList ) {
        if(config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
             wifiManager.disconnect();
             wifiManager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true);
             wifiManager.reconnect();               
             return true;
        }           
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ok you are right. But i still unable to connect. wifi turn off and then back to its previously connected network. This seems to be a android give a preference to a default network first in a save network list. is it any way to remove this metwork from default one and then add a new in default?

Comment: @user526206 First remove all wifi profiles from device, and configure them again.

Comment: Thanks. Well proper way is to disable connected Network also like:   wifiManager.disconnect();         wifiManager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true); wifiManager.disableNetwork(connectedNetwork);    wifiManager.reconnect();